# Alinear cabecera y texto

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un fichero de texto con el resultado de una consulta quiero que quede alineado encabezdo y resultado.
actualemte se ve asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es le codigo

```
public void crearFichero(List<Proveedor> listaProveedores) throws IOException {
        FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter("Resultado.txt");
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fichero);
            bw.write("id nombre  fecha alta  idCliente \n");
            for (Proveedor proveedor : listaProveedores) {
                bw.write(proveedor.toString() + "\n");
            }
            bw.close();
            fichero.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IOException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: prueba con `\t`.

Comment: donde exactamente?

Comment: del to String que tiene la clase proveedor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una idea seria hacer uso de [String format](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) el cual te permite devolver una cadena formateada

ejemplo

1 modificar el metodo ToString() de la clase Proveedor

```
public String toString(){
String value= String.format("%1$2s %2$11s %3$11s %4$3s",getId(),getNombre(),getFecha(),getId_cliente());
return value;
}
```

Ten presente que "%2s" indica que se muestre una cadena de hasta 2 caracteres, por lo que si tu cadena es de un caracter, llenara con espacio en blanco el primer caracter. La misma logica en "%11s" las cuales las uso para el nombre y la fecha los cuales son los mas largos, obviamente podes aumentar la longitud dependiendo de los nombres de tus proveedores

2 Modificar el encabezado

```
bw.write(String.format("%1$2s %2$11s %3$11s %4$3s","Id","Nombre","Fecha Alta","Id Cliente")+"\n");
```

los mismos valores que el toString para una similitud

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]